# using pdfbox with src code and not jar

Tags: pdfbox

I am trying to edit some classes of pdfbox with private data members.So I copied the org folder and pasted it in my src folder . Now when I am creating an object of PdfTextStripper class I am getting an error named "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError"
This is part of the code inside PdfTextStripper class where exception is happening

```
static
{
    String path = "org/apache/pdfbox/resources/text/BidiMirroring.txt";

    InputStream input =    PDFTextStripper.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
    try
    {
        parseBidiFile(input);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        LOG.warn("Could not parse BidiMirroring.txt, mirroring char map will be empty: "
                + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            input.close();// error is in this line
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            LOG.error("Could not close BidiMirroring.txt ", e);
        }
    }
};
```

So compiler points to this line as an error. 
Why is this exception happening. When I use jar file then I dont get any exception so why am i getting one now? How to solve this?

Comment: You only mention ***the** org folder*. Probably you only copied from the sources (`src/main/java`) and not the resources (`src/main/resources`)? Pdfbox has a number of resources it needs.

Comment: Yes That's correct. I resolved it Yesterday by copying resources folder.

Comment: I that case please simply create an answer to that effect here and accept it as soon as you are allowed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any any one faces similar problem, just copy the resources folder too. It worked for me.